# localtunnel server returned an error, please try again

Tags: localtunnel

When I run `lt --port 8000` I have this issue:

> localtunnel server returned an error, please try again

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Are you running on your own server? or just connecting your local to internet

Comment: please refrain from posting screenshot when a copy/paste of the error message is all that is needed.

Comment: Error: localtunnel server returned an error, please try again
    at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/lib/Tunnel.js:53:27)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/_request@2.81.0@request/request.js:188:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:159:13)

Comment: at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/_request@2.81.0@request/request.js:1171:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/_request@2.81.0@request/request.js:1091:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:254:19)

Comment: I run my server at port 8000

Answer (score 0):

The cloud-hosted part of Localtunnel [was down around the time you posted this question](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/205).

It appears to be working again.

Answer (score 0):

For your second error, `http://helloworld.com:2000` is not a localtunnel server, which cause this output. The `--host` option means to connect the localtunnel server on port of the hostname.

If you want to use this feature, you will have to setup a localtunnel server for yourself through the instruction [here](https://github.com/localtunnel/server). Yet remember not to use subdomain for this as it is not yet supported.